# MySql single table optimization options

Tags: mysql

I have a table with around 6 million rows and has many columns with lot of data.

I want to implement a search functionality on this table mostly based on date range when the row was created and some other columns.

No other table is required so no question of joins in query. Also, I have implemented indexes on date column and other relevant columns.

Still the search takes long time if I search for large ranges, considering number of rows the table has. I have increased key_buffer_size to 1G and also mysql_query_cache to 500M.

I want to know if,

1. There is anything else I can do, optimizing any other variables that may increase performance.
2. Should I look into re-designing the table itself?

I want to explore all options before increasing RAM or CPU.

**UPDATE**:

Below are more details

CPU: Intel Quadcore
RAM: 4GB
OS: CentOS

```
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| deal_id                     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| deal_group_id               | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                | 
| site_id                     | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| datetime                    | char(14)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |  
| deal_category               | varchar(200)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| vendor_name                 | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| area                        | varchar(200)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| address                     | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |  
| country_code                | varchar(5)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| expired                     | int(1)        | NO   |     | 0       |                | 
| type                        | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | REGULAR |                | 
| pn_id                       | int(11)       | NO   |     | 0       |                | 
+-----------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Above is the schema. In the where clause the combination of `datetime` in range, `deal_category`, `vendor_name` in like and `country_code` is used. All are indexed. Below is one sample query

`SELECT distinct t.deal_id, t.deal_group_id, t.site_name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.datetime) as datetime, t.deal_category as deal_category, t.vendor_name, t.area as area, t.country_code FROM table t WHERE 1 AND t.country_code = 'US' AND datetime BETWEEN '20110601' AND '20120303' limit 10;`

I have increased `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to around 75%, it has improved the performance for some queries, but still takes lot of time if all filters are included.

Below is the my.cnf file settings,

`query_cache_size=500M`

`max_allowed_packet= 1G`

`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G`

`key_buffer_size = 1G`

This table is quite busy, there are hundreds of writes happening every minute.

Hope this gives clearer picture.

**More Updates**

Below is the explain output and indexes on table,

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys         | key          | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ref  | country_code,datetime | country_code | 17      | const | 521556 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------+--------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

Indexes:

```
+-------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| table       |          0 | PRIMARY           |            1 | deal_id       | A         |     5810775 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| table       |          0 | PRIMARY           |            2 | deal_group_id | A         |     5810775 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| table       |          1 | site_id           |            1 | site_id       | A         |        2109 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |        | 
| table       |          1 | area              |            1 | area          | A         |       18927 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| table       |          1 | country_code      |            1 | country_code  | A         |          20 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| table       |          1 | deal_group_id     |            1 | deal_group_id | A         |     1936925 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         | 
| table       |          1 | deal_category     |            1 | deal_category | A         |          20 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
| table       |          1 | datetime          |            1 | datetime      | A         |     5810775 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         | 
+-------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Thanks

Comment: without any knowledge about the table structure etc. any answer would be pure speculation... provide much more details...

Comment: It really depends on your read/write profile. How often is this table written to compared to how often it's read? What sort of read queries are the most common? Are the date ranges natural (i.e. do the ranges coincide with the calendar) or bespoke? It may be better to denormalise the data in some way. Please post the schema, some sample data and some sample queries.

Comment: 1. In your query you need to remove WHERE 1  which

Comment: Could you please post `EXPLAIN` output from that query? Also, `SHOW INDEXES FROM tableName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For a database running Innodb you need to increase the value of innodb_buffer_pool_size to about 70 - 80% available RAM on a dedicated server so that as much of the data as possible can fit in memory
2. Create a single index containing the fields that you are going to search on
3. Searches with LIKE %value% do not use indexes

For additional tuning you need to provide more information on the schema and searches you will be carrying out

1. Remove the '1 AND' comparison in the WHERE clause
2. Change datetime BETWEEN '20110601' AND '20120303' to DATE(datetime) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('20110601', '%Y%m%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('20120303', '%Y%m%d'). I am assuming that the datetime field contains dates in the MySQL format
3. Consider changing the datetime field from a char(14) to a datetime field for faster computations
4. If the country_code column only has 2 digit country codes consider changing its size to char(2)
5. Remove DISTINCT before deal_id column which is an autoincrement and primary key

Comment: Thanks @ssmusoke, I have updated my post also increased innodb_buffer_pool_size, it improved but still lot is left wanting though

Comment: `1 AND …` should be removed by the query optimizer and make no significant performance difference. If that isn't the case, I'd file a MySQL bug report.

Comment: The datetime field contains date but its not in mysql format. Bad design, I agree.

Comment: I accepted this as accepted answer as doing the points mentioned here did achieve some gain in performance. I guess I have to change the HW specs to achieve better performance.

Comment: Thank you, btw what MySQL and InnoDB version are you running? Are you using the InnoDB plugin? Are you also running a 64bit OS, because increasing RAM may help.

Comment: About advice No5: You can't simply remove `DISTINCT` in all cases. `DISTINCT` is not a function and is applied to the whole row, not one column only.

Comment: @ypercube the deal_id column is an auto-increment making each row in the resultset unique making DISTINCT redundant, however if the deal_id column is not included in the result-set then DISTINCT can produce unique rows